# How to precize that a pattern should start with a letter

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find all the links in a text. It's a messy text, and there are some cases that I wanna avoid. I wanna extract only links.

```
d= re.findall(r'.href=\\"http://([^"]*)', text)
dd= ['http://'+x for x in d]
```

How can I do it with regular expression without re-adding http later.

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: use a dedicated html parsing library (BeautifulSoup is one that is often recommended), rather than regex.

Comment: BeatifulSoup didn't work with me, I had a messy html. Instead of that, I converted the html to a text, and used regular expression to get the links

Comment: Can you provide an example text and your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Changes made**

- Rearrange the paranthesis so as to wrap the `http://` as well
- You need not escape the `"` in the raw string
- Drop the `.` before the `http`

The statment can be

```
d= re.findall(r'href="(http://[^"]*)', text)
```

**Test**

```
>>> str='href="http://www.google.com"'
>>> re.findall(r'href="(http://[^"]*)', str)
['http://www.google.com']
```

Comment: Simple and efficient! thanks. I am getting links from JS. So I need to decode them as well.

Comment: @user3378649 You are welcome :) you can tweak the regex to add further validation required.